# Regex to replace the match only at start of string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match phone number using regex by stripping unwanted prefixes like 0, *, # and +

e.g.

```
+*#+0#01231340010
```

should produce,

```
1231340010
```

I am using python re module

I tried following,

```
re.sub(r'[0*#+]', '', '+*#+0#01231340010')
```

but it is removing later 0s too.

I tried to use regex groups, but still it's not working ( or I am doing something wrong for sure ).

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Delgan I tried that, but it only removes single occurrence of first matching character producing - 00091700

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the start of the string check (`^`) and `*` quantifier (0 or more occurences):

```
>>> re.sub(r'^[0*#+]*', '', '+*#+0#01231340010')
'1231340010'
```

Or, a non-regex approach using [`itertools.dropwhile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile):

```
>>> from itertools import dropwhile
>>> not_allowed = {'0', '*', '#', '+'}
>>> ''.join(dropwhile(lambda x: x in not_allowed, s))
'1231340010'
```

Comment: What if the prefix list grows longer?Or some of the "prefixes" cannot be forseen? I suggest  a `^[^1-9]+` regex to just grab all characters other than `1` to `9` from the beginning, and remove them. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38776948/3832970), it seems to be more generic for the current task.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah, yours is a more generic and a better way to approach the problem, thanks

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you are doing is trying to remove everything before the first digit from `[1-9]` range in the string. It is *safer* then to use

```
re.sub(r'^[^1-9]+', '', input)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pM7wJ3/1)

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^1-9]+` - 1 or more (`+`) characters other than digits from 1-9 range (excluding `0`)

I say "safer" meaning that there can be other prefixes not enumerated in the question, like `p`, etc.

Comment: thanks @Wiktor. For now I am not bothering p , and w. but this is really important point. really appreciating your answer.

Comment: Just FYI: alecxe's `dropwhile` will also work with this approach, see [this Python demo](http://ideone.com/tPq2gn). Just define what is allowed and check with `not in`.

Comment: Please do not rush with answer accepting, note that if you accept an answer and next day change your mind, the person who asked loses 15 points.

Comment: Sorry for this. I am new to stackoveflow. Honestly, I didn't know this.

Comment: I thought we can accept 2 answers at same time. After your comment I realized it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the `^` to mark only from the beginning and add a `*` to get any that appear

```
re.sub(r'^[0*#+]*', '', '+*#+0#01231340010')
#'1231340010'
```

Answer (score 1):

Anchor the regex to the start of the string with '^'. e.g.

```
re.sub(r'^[0*#+]', '', ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following regex:

```
0*(\d+)$
```

It will match all digits from the end except leading zeros.